# Chatbot training platform that supports Arabic

Tags: nlp, arabic, ibm-watson, chatbot, wit.ai

I am looking for a **chatbot training platform** (like IBM Watson Conversation Service or api.ai) that has **Arabic support**.

I know wit.ai has a support for Arabic but reading their blogpost it seems like it's in Beta. Moreover, it has been suggested that wit.ai is suited towards to hobbyists and is not advisable to build complex conversational bots with it.

So I want to know whether there exists any service for chatbot training (**except wit.ai**) that has Arabic support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer in
[IBM support forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/296335/when-will-arabic-be-supported-in-the-conversation/) It should happen by the end of 2016